# Jquery to enable/disable a drop down list on checking/unchecking a check box in Ruby

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ruby and jQuery as well.

I have a drop down list which should be enabled/disabled on checking/unchecking a check box.It would be of great help if someone could help with the jQuery for this.

thanks,
Ramya.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#yourCheckBoxId").change(function(){
        if($(this).attr("disabled").length)
        {
            $("#yourDropDownId").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#yourDropDownId").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

(untested)

Comment: hi ,I have one more query what do i have to have in the :disabled attribute of the select_tag.safe_concat select_tag "user", 
            options_from_collection_for_select(testers, "id", "name", get_selected_user(cycle_ic_revision_assignment, platform_config)),
            :id => "select_#{rev_assign_id}_#{platform_config_id}",
            :class => "add_ic_run_user"

Comment: You just have to change the checkboxid and the dropdownid. The disabled="disabled" is set and removed by the script. You should do nothing with that. If this doesn't answers your question I didn't understand you correctly :).

Comment: Hi ,My question is like in the select_tag "user", options_from_collection_for_select(testers, "id", "name", get_selected_user(cycle_ic_revision_assignment, platform_config)), :id => "select_#{rev_assign_id}_#{platform_config_id}", :class => "add_ic_run_user" do i have to set the :disabled=>true or not

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your are asking. This is something completely different and without code it's difficult to say. Please ask another question separate from this one.

Comment: $('.add_ic_run').live("change", function(){ $.ajaxSetup({beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")); }}); id = $(this).attr('id') cycle_rev_assign_id = id.split("_")[1] platform_id = id.split("_")[2] id1="select_"+cycle_rev_assign_id+"_"+platform_id if($(this).attr("checked")) { alert($( id1)) $("#user").removeAttr("disabled") } else { $("#user").attr("disabled", true) } This is my ajax code.......Here id1 gives me the id of my select box. Please let me know how to use it to enable/disable withit

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of jquery support .prop method.

example: $("#dropdownid").prop("disabled", "true")